# Adding transparent PNG to SWF in SwfDotNet library (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, flash

The SwfDotNet library seems to be a great library for crating swfs from code, in VB.NET.

Unfortunately it is poorly documented, and examples are scarce.

I would like to know how to add a transparent PNG to a SWF frame, lossless, or jpeg compressed.

I know it has something to do with DefineBitsJpeg3Tag, but I cant manage to make it work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SwfDotNet, but I do know the SWF file format.

There are two approaches you can take:

1) Use the DefineBitsLossless2 tag with format tag of 5 (32bit ARGB buffer). This will give you "Native" lossless data with SWF's default compression (zlib).

2) Use the DefineBitsJPEG3 tag and embed a PNG file. Flash player specification supports that.